# Ember masonry not working correctly

Tags: ember.js, jquery-masonry

I have used ember Masonry addon in my app.Everything is working fine.But when the grid has more photos and the internet is slow it load all the photo one above another till all the photos are downloaded.Once all the photo is downloaded then it form the grid.This should not happen and its not looking good.It should load all the photo for once before showing any photo.Once all are downloaded it should show.Mean while I can show some loading icon

index.hbs

```
{{#masonry-grid gutter=10 items=usrPhotos as |photo|}}
```

I don't how to fix it.Please add sample code to answer.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a loading template for the route to display while it is resolving the model

Comment: Can you give some example or sample code I am new to ember

Comment: Add a template called loading.hbs beside your index.hbs it should display until the model is resolved